# Enroll user on course module error due to permissions

Tags: users, views

I want that a role called "Profesor" can enroll users on a course created using the course module, using the course-enrollments/search-add view but I'm getting the following error:

Type: views bulk operation
User: profesor1
Message: Skipped Enroll user on user alumno2 due to insufficient permissions.

Here is my permissions configuration:
[image: Permissions configuration]

Administrator can enroll users, any help?

EDIT:

The course permissions are configured as follows:
[image: Course module permissions]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the course module in quite a while but aren't there other permissions specific to the module itself?

Comment: Yes, the course module includes other permissions, I have edited the question with the configuration

Comment: Hey Niall, I think there is another explanation / answer for this question. Curious about your feedback on it ...

Comment: I am totally out of touch with this module by now Pierre but my opinion of education modules in general is that they should all be avoided. Everything they offer can be achieved with clever use of the key well-supported modules that work well together. I don't mean to insult the creators of said modules because isolated, they work very well. But by nature, an LMS is one of the most complex site builds possible and specific modules make it needlessly complex in the long-run.. Serious technical debt when adding something simple like badges or points etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be similar to the VBO issue "[Custom Action Stopped Working](https://www.drupal.org/node/2527646)", which  includes some possible work around (such as going back to a prior VBO release, if that's what you want to consider ...).

But this issue also appears to be related to "[Default action behaviors in getAccessMask()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2254871)". And that issue contains a patch attached to comment nr 29, which in subsequent comments seems to confirm that it does solve the issue (I've not QA-tested that patch ...).